# Add the shortcodes from the enfold theme to the other theme

Tags: php, themes, shortcode, child-theme

A WordPress website uses the enfold theme and its content is created with the avia page builder. We have created a new template when it displays the text with the theme of the previous code shortcodes. How do I transfer shortcodes to a new template?

Comment: make it a child theme of your current theme?

Comment: @Vishwa I did nothing for the child theme, please give me more tips. I would remind you that the new theme is completely different from the previous one

Comment: your question is lil unclear. explain more. more the details, easier to help

Comment: @Vishwa We already used the enfold theme, we used avia builder to build the page. The avia builder uses shortcodes. Now! The new theme that we installed, the text of the page is converted into a series of unspecified code, my question is. How to add shortcodes in a new theme, so that the text is displayed correctly.

Comment: do you have avia builder activated on your new wp installation?

Comment: @Vishwa avia builder for theme enfold and there is no one alone. Which can not be installed

Comment: when you created the template using avia builder, it basically created shortcodes and theme itself renders them(or by avia plugin(?)) which renders the page you see in the browser. So basically to decode avia shortcodes, you need to use avia builder inside your new theme.

Comment: @Vishwa I understood . But the avia plugin does not exist. [link] (https://www.google.com/search?q=avia+layout+builder&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIR811AT818&oq=avia&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j69i60j69i59j35i39j0l2.2570j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: then it could be some extension that came bundled with the theme. ask theme developers if you can decode the avia builder codes

Comment: Can not just add sortcodes to the new template?

Comment: probably not. to display as a html web page, shortcodes need to be parsed/decoded. I guess avia builder did that previously. without that your shortcodes will just rendered as normal text (what you have now)